# How to transfer id_edit_copy msg in the activex control

Tags: mfc, grid, activex

I put the cgridctrl embed into the activex control which used  mfc.
The cgridctrl  can't deal with the  msg.
I have overwrite the oncmdmsg function.
code:
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if (m_pGridCtrl && IsWindow(m_pGridCtrl->m_hWnd))
    {

```
    if (m_pGridCtrl->OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

return CDialog::OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo);
```

m_pGridCtrl->OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo)  return false.

Anyone can give me  suggestion?

Comment: It's because the  activex control  is unfocus.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the  activex control is unfocus.
I make it use the follow code.

OnActivateInPlace(TRUE, NULL);

Add it to the virtual function oncreate   and OnMouseActivate which deal with the Mouseactiveate msg.